# makefile does not see functions defined from bashrc

Tags: bash, function, makefile, export

I have following function in .bashrc

```
...
delete_exe(){
    for i in $@; do
        if [ -x "$i" ]; then
            rm "$i"
        fi
    done
}
```

Now when I type

```
user@Host:~/Desktop/bin/2$ type delete_exe
delete_exe is a function
delete_exe () 
{ 
    for i in $@;
    do
        if [ -x "$i" ]; then
            rm "$i";
        fi;
    done
}
```

The bash see it corretly. However, using it in makefile:

```
clean:
    delete_exe *
```

gives:

```
user@Host:~/Desktop/bin/2$ make clean
/bin/sh: 1: delete_exe: not found
make: *** [makefile:9: clean] Error 127
```

Now do I need to export that function? If so, do I have to export **every single** function I declare in `.bashrc` or source a file with that function from `.bashrc`?? Why does shell sees it but other programs (such as make) do not?

Comment: Functions aren't exported by default, and `make` doesn't use `bash` so it wouldn't be able to use exported functions anyway.

Comment: So in other words. I have to export every function defined in bash?

Comment: No, in other words you can't use shell functions in makefiles.

Comment: Exporting functions is a bash extension, and `make` doesn't use `bash`, it uses `sh`.

Comment: And it's just a bad idea to try to do this, since it means the makefile can only be used by users with the same shell functions.

Comment: `delete_exe` does not depend on the current shell environment and should therefore be a separate script instead of a function. This way it'll work from anywhere, including Make. I'd use `find` directly in Make though, so other people don't need my special scripts.

Comment: But I do not want to write whole shell commands directly to makefile. That would mess the makefile. Should I defined make-function or bash file/function and use it in makefile?

Answer (score 1):

`delete_exe` is not usable from your Makefile for two reasons: bash does not export functions by default and the default make shell is not bash. Of course, you can work around these by explicitly exporting your function (`export -f`) and explicitly using bash as your make shell (`SHELL := bash`) but the losses in terms of portability, safety and maintainability would be huge.

Replacing:

```
delete_exe *
```

in your recipe by:

```
for i in ./*; do if [ -x "$$i" ]; then rm "$$i"; fi; done
```

is not that messy. Pay attention to the `$$` instead of `$`. They are needed to escape the make expansion of the recipe before passing it to the shell.

If you really prefer a compact form you can also define a make variable:

```
delete_exe := for i in ./*; do if [ -x "$$i" ]; then rm "$$i"; fi; done

clean:
    $(delete_exe)
```

Note: there is a potential problem with your shell function which is that, unless you set the `nullglob` bash option, `*` expands as a literal `*` if no visible files or directories are present (same problem with the recipes I suggest and the `./*` pattern). In this case it is not an issue because the literal `*` will be filtered out by the `[ -x ]` test but it is good to remember: in other circumstances we can easily imagine more problematic effects.

Note: I used `./*` instead of `*` for security reasons (see, for instance, [Filenames and Pathnames in Shell: How to do it Correctly](https://dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html) by David A. Wheeler).